# OpenVX sample program crashed with illegal instruction

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, caffe, intel, openvx

I have installed *Intel Computer Vision SDK*, to use *ModelOptimizer* with *caffe* from [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/model-optimizer-devguide-introducing-deep-learning-model-optimizer).
Installation was successful and using ModelOptimizer, OpenVX code was generated along with normalized weights. From the generated code main.c was compiled successfully along with its dependencies. When i am running the generated binary its showing illegal instruction.

```
Program received signal SIGILL, Illegal instruction.
0x00007fffee0d3cbc in Xbyak::Operand::Operand(int, Xbyak::Operand::Kind, int, bool) ()
   from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libmkldnn.so.0
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.17-106.el7_2.4.x86_64 libgcc-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64 libstdc++-4.8.5-4.el7.x86_64
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007fffee0d3cbc in Xbyak::Operand::Operand(int, Xbyak::Operand::Kind, int, bool) ()
   from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libmkldnn.so.0
#1  0x00007fffee0c72a2 in __sti__$E () from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libmkldnn.so.0
#2  0x00007ffff7dea3a3 in _dl_init_internal () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#3  0x00007ffff7deeab6 in dl_open_worker () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#4  0x00007ffff7dea1b4 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#5  0x00007ffff7dee1ab in _dl_open () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#6  0x00007fffef3b402b in dlopen_doit () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#7  0x00007ffff7dea1b4 in _dl_catch_error () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#8  0x00007fffef3b462d in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#9  0x00007fffef3b40c1 in dlopen@@GLIBC_2.2.5 () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#10 0x00007ffff79b7290 in vxLoadModule(char*) () from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libiap_openvx.so.1.0
#11 0x00007ffff79c3fde in vxLoadTarget(_vx_context*, char*) () from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libiap_openvx.so.1.0
#12 0x00007ffff794fb51 in vxCreateContext () from /home/vehiscan/intel/computer_vision_sdk_2017.0.113/openvx/lib/libiap_openvx.so.1.0
#13 0x0000000000401a26 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe228) at main.c:44
```

> Below is my machine configuration:-
>
> OS         : CentOS-7.2
>
> Processor  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3720QM CPU @ 2.60GHz
>
> Graphics   : Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

Is there anything i am missing or doing wrong?

PS: please let me know if the above information is not sufficient.

Comment: ask in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/computer-vision

Comment: These are platform specific issues and not openVX. Make sure your platform specific openVX libraries are in order.